# How can I connect to a local computer behind a router with the router's IP address?

Tags: routing

I am trying to set up an IPA server to be used from machines that share the same network as the server and machines that don't.

The router's IP address is 12.34.56.78

I am using port forwarding on the router to route the IPA ports and 22 to 192.168.1.100

On machine 192.168.1.101, I can ssh to 192.168.1.100.

On machine some.public.machine.not.on.network, I can ssh to 12.34.56.78.

On machine 192.168.1.101, I can NOT ssh to 12.34.56.78.

What can I change on the router at 12.34.56.78 to allow 192.168.1.101 to access the ports at 192.168.1.100 through 12.34.56.78?

Reasoning: I have machines that will need to authenticate through the IPA server that may be connected locally or remotely.

I have telnet access to the router.

EDIT: For the machines that will always be on the local network, I can do `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 12.34.56.78 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100` -- This won't work for machines that are sometimes on, sometimes off, which is why I'm looking for a solution on the router level.

EDIT2: The router is an off-the-shelf product, the Technicolor C2000T. I can telnet in from a local computer, and the output of `iptables -t nat -nvL` is:

> iptables -t nat -nvL
>   Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 20244 packets, 1384K bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  ppp2   *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4
>    7762  470K CapPort    tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>    446K   33M WanPrerouting  all  --  ppp2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>
> Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 446K packets, 33M bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>       0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ppp2    10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0
>       0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ppp2    172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0
>   13303  906K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ppp2    192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 446 packets, 75081 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain CapPort (1 references)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain DMZ (1 references)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain PortMap (1 references)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>       1    40 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 to:192.168.1.100:443 
>       0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:636 to:192.168.1.100:636 
>       6   300 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.1.100:80 
>       0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:389 to:192.168.1.100:389 
>       0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:88 to:192.168.1.100:88 
>       0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:88 to:192.168.1.100:88 
>       0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:464 to:192.168.1.100:464 
>       0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:464 to:192.168.1.100:464 
>       0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 to:192.168.1.100:53 
>    445K   33M DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 to:192.168.1.100:53 
>       2   260 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:123 to:192.168.1.100:123 
>       0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:7389 to:192.168.1.100:7389 
>     173  9836 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 to:192.168.1.100:22
>
> Chain Redirects (1 references)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain TechDNAT (1 references)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain WanPrerouting (1 references)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>    446K   33M Redirects  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>    446K   33M TechDNAT   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>    446K   33M PortMap    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>     472 45291 DMZ        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Your description is really hard to understand, the whole picture cannot be seen. A detailed drawing with machines and **all the IP addresses** would probably help. However, there is a quite general problem with port forwarding: you _have to_ make sure the reply traffic from the server goes back through the port forwarding device. This means that the client may not have an IP address on the same subnet as the server. You may also implement source NAT (MASQUERADING) for the port forwarded traffic as a workaround, but then you'll not be able to see the source addresses on the server.

Comment: Is this router an off-the-shelf product, or do you have a linux box acting as a router? If this is just a linux box, we need to see the iptables rules on it (`iptables -t nat -nvL` or `iptables-save`).